# All Tasks..Advanced Operations option missing from Certificates MMC Snap-In

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2003-r2

I am trying to follow the instructions in [this article](http://techontip.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/how-to-create-a-san-certificate-signing-request-for-iis-web-server/) to create a custom certificate to support SSL on a web server.

I'm stuck on the following step:

> Click on Personal – All Tasks – Advanced Operations – Create Custom
>   request

The problem is that on the web server (Windows Server 2003 R2) **I don't have an "Advanced Operations" option under "All Tasks"**. I do on my desktop machine (Windows 7), but not on the server. All the documentation I can find indicates that it should be available on WS-2003-R2, but it just isn't.

**Note:** I'm going through this manual process because I need to specify a alternate host names in the CSR, which you can't do through the IIS 6.0 console certificate managment functionality.

Any suggestions for how to make this option show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That menu option is not a feature on Windows 2003 R2.

You may want to do this through the command line, it is more flexible.

**How to use the Certreq.exe utility to create and submit a certificate request that includes a SAN**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931351

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736326%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/niraj_kumar/archive/2009/02/11/how-to-request-certificate-from-third-party-ca-and-install-it-on-the-machine.aspx

```
certreq -new request.inf certnew.req

certreq -accept cert.cer

C:\UTIL>certreq -v -?
certreq.exe: 5.2.3790.1830 retail (srv03_sp1_rtm.050324-1447)
Usage:
  CertReq -?
  CertReq [-v] -?
  CertReq [-Command] -?

  CertReq [-Submit] [Options] [RequestFileIn [CertFileOut [CertChainFileOut [FullResponseFileOut]]]]
    Submit a request to a Certification Authority.
    -attrib AttributeString
    -binary
    -config ConfigString
    -crl
    -rpc

  CertReq -Retrieve [Options] RequestId [CertFileOut [CertChainFileOut [FullResponseFileOut]]]
    Retrieve a response to a previous request from a Certification Authority.
    -binary
    -config ConfigString
    -crl
    -rpc

  CertReq -New [Options] [PolicyFileIn [RequestFileOut]]
    Create a new request as directed by PolicyFileIn
    -attrib AttributeString
    -binary
    -cert CertId

  CertReq -Accept [CertChainFileIn | FullResponseFileIn | CertFileIn]
    Accept and install a response to a previous new request.

  CertReq -Policy [Options] [RequestFileIn [PolicyFileIn [RequestFileOut [PKCS10FileOut]]]]
    Construct a cross certification or qualified subordination request
    from an existing CA certificate or from an existing request.
    -attrib AttributeString
    -binary
    -cert CertId

  CertReq -Sign [Options] [RequestFileIn [RequestFileOut]]
    Sign a cross certification or qualified subordination request.
    -binary
    -cert CertId
    -crl

Description:
  -any                    - Force ICertRequest::Submit to determine encoding type
  -attrib AttributeString - Request attribute string
  -binary                 - Output files in binary format instead of Base64-encoded
  -cert CertId            - Specify signing certificate by common name,
                            serial number, or by sha-1 Key or cert hash
  -config ConfigString    - Server\CertificationAuthority config string
                            or use a single minus sign (-) as config string
  -crl                    - Include CRLs in CertChainFileOut or
                            RequestFileOut
  -f                      - Force overwrite of existing files
  -q                      - Suppress all interactive dialogs
  -rpc                    - Use RPC instead of DCOM server connection
  -v                      - Display Full Response Properties
  -?                      - Display this usage message

  RequestFileIn           - Base64-encoded or binary input file name:
                            PKCS10 certificate request,
                            CMS certificate request,
                            PKCS7 certificate renewal request,
                            X-509 certificate to be cross-certified, or
                            KeyGen tag format certificate request
  RequestFileOut          - Base64-encoded output file name
  PKCS10FileOut           - Base64-encoded PKCS10 output file name
  CertFileOut             - Base64-encoded X-509 file name
  CertChainFileOut        - Base64-encoded PKCS7 file name
  FullResponseFileOut     - Base64-encoded Full Response file name
  ConfigString            - Backslash separated Server Name and Certification
                            Authority Name: MachineDnsName\CAName
  AttributeString         - Colon separated Name and Value string pairs
                            Each pair separated by a backslash and "n"
                            Example: "Name1: Value1\n Name2: Value2"
  PolicyFileIn            - INF file containing a textual representation
                            of extensions used to qualify a request

[NewRequest]
    Subject = "CN=..,OU=...,DC=..."
    PrivateKeyArchive = TRUE
    KeySpec = 1
    KeyLength = 1024
    RenewalCert = CertId
    SMIME = TRUE
    Exportable = TRUE
    UserProtected = TRUE
    KeyContainer = "..."
    MachineKeySet = TRUE
    Silent = TRUE
    ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
    ProviderType = 1
    UseExistingKeySet = TRUE
    RequesterName = DOMAIN\User
    RequestType = PKCS10 | PKCS10- | PKCS7 | CMC
    KeyUsage = 0x80
    EncipherOnly = TRUE
```